# Загрузка html+js в iframe

Tags: html, javascript, iframe

Как можно загрузить во фрейме страницу? При чем HTML и JS код я получаю отдельно.
Сейчас я делаю вот так, но всплывают определенные косяки:

```
// добавление HTML в body
window.frames['result_frame'].document.body.innerHTML = HTMLCodeEditor.getValue();      
// добавление скрипта
var cs = window.frames['result_frame'].document.createElement('script');
cs.innerHTML = JSCodeEditor.getValue();
window.frames['result_frame'].document.head.appendChild(cs);
```

Итак, о косяках:

- если в body был добавлен стиль или
     обработчик событий, то он там и
     остается
- при добавлении нового скрипта, старый
     остается
- были случаи когда html код добавлялся не сразу, а только со второй попытки

UPD1: второй косяк исправил, удаляя скрипт вот так: cs.parentNode.removeChild(cs);
У меня что-то вроде песочницы, отсюда и старый код во фрейме. А сам iframe создается в html.
UPD2:
нашел как очистить весь фрейм, так что решилось сразу несколько проблем

```
document.getElementById('result_frame').contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = ""
```

Comment: в данный момент косяки неопределенные, не могли бы вы их немного описать.

Comment: а как вы создаете  фрейм ? (что за  старые стили/скрипты ?)

Comment: [вот про что я говорил](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/W7XL6/)

Comment: спасибо, все косяки исправил